# How do I enable/set multicast rules using firewalld in RHEL7 / CentOS 7

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, multicast

I cannot find docs on how to enable multicast for firewalld which is the default firewall in RHEL / CentOS 7. Can some enlighten me? FYI: I know how to do it using iptables.

Comment: Well: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1587673

Answer (score 5):

At first I tried this command:

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter IN_public_allow 1 -d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT
```

but it seems that CentOS7 cannot reload direct rules after reboot.

```
[root@test01-galera02 firewalld]# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
[root@test01-galera02 firewalld]# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules --permanent
ipv4 filter IN_public_allow 1 -d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT
[root@test01-galera02 firewalld]# 
[root@test01-galera02 firewalld]# cat direct.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
  <rule priority="1" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="IN_public_allow">-d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT</rule>
</direct>
[root@test01-galera02 firewalld]# pwd
/etc/firewalld
[root@test01-galera02 firewalld]#
```

Second, I successfully used this command. firewalld runs fine now on my galera cluster with keepalived on it.

```
 firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="224.0.0.18" protocol value="ip" accept' --permanent
 firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: +1, but I had to change `protocol value` from `ip` to `2`. Otherwise I was getting `ERROR: INVALID_PROTOCOL: ip`, because `/etc/protocol` has no such name. I used the `2` because the REJECT logs stated `PROTO=2`.

Comment: Ah, btw: I did not use anything but the last command `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="224.0.0.18" protocol value="ip" accept' --permanent`. I did not even do the `--reload`. I guess modern versions of firewalld handle that themselves. `0.7.1` version is here *(note also, nowadays it's not using iptables by default)*.

Answer (score 2):

Variant for **IPv4** multicast and **Firewalld** using *rich-rules*:

- Define rules:

  ```bash
  ALLOW_MULTICAST_RICH_RULE="
    rule family=ipv4
    destination address=224.0.0.0/4
    protocol value=udp
    accept"
  ALLOW_IGMP_RICH_RULE="
    rule family=ipv4
    protocol value=igmp
    accept"
  ```
- Apply the rules at runtime:

  ```bash
  firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule="$ALLOW_MULTICAST_RICH_RULE"
  firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule="$ALLOW_IGMP_RICH_RULE"
  ```
- Add rules permanently (i.e. they will apply after reboot):

  ```bash
  firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="$ALLOW_MULTICAST_RICH_RULE"
  firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="$ALLOW_IGMP_RICH_RULE"
  ```

In addition to **CentOS 7**, this also works in **RHEL/CentOS/Rocky/AlmaLinux 8**, in which [*direct* rules are not supported by default](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-and-configuring-firewalld_configuring-and-managing-networking):

> Note that `firewalld` with `nftables` backend does not support passing
> custom `nftables` rules to `firewalld`, using the `--direct` option.

Answer (score 1):

IPv6

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter PREROUTING 0 -t raw -m rpfilter --invert -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter INPUT 0 -d ff00::/8 -j ACCEPT
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv6 filter OUTPUT 0 -d ff00::/8 -j ACCEPT
```

IPv4

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -m udp -p udp -m pkttype --pkt-type multicast -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You open this file: `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml`.
Write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
<rule priority="0" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="OUTPUT">' --out-interface' [ens33] --destination 224.0.0.18 --protocol vrrp -j ACCEPT</rule>
<rule priority="1" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="IN_public_allow">-d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT</rule>
</direct>
```

Replace `[ens33]` with your server's port.
Then: `firewall-cmd --reload`.

Answer (score 0):

you open file: /etc/firewalld/direct.xml write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>
<rule priority="1" table="filter" ipv="ipv4" chain="IN_public_allow">-d 
224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT</rule>
</direct>
```

replace ens33 to your server's port 
then: firewall-cmd --reload